Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No route to host
i have codeigniter 3.1.11 on ubuntu 24 and i am not able to connect mysql
here my error message

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No route to host

even my username and password are correct and i am able to connect through ssh terminal

Please help
